# how to disabled some select button's option depending upon another input field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dom

I have a select button with 3 options. I have another text box above. Depending upon the text box's value I want to make one of the option disabled using javascript.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<label for="name">Name of the candidate: </label><br>
<input type="text" name="e_name" value="<%=e.getName() %>" onfocus="ViewType(this.value);">
<br><br>
<label for="division">Choose Division</label><br>
<select name="e_division" id="selectbtn"><option>Select One</option><option>MECH</option><option>CSE</option><option>CE</option></select>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function ViewType(val){
var op=document.getElementById("selectbtn");
for(var i=0;i<=op.length();i++){
if(val == "Amit"){
op.option[1].disabled=true;
op.option[2].disabled=true;
}
}
}
```

Means here if the name is "Amit" then only "MECH" option will be visible. For any other name all options will be visible.

Comment: Use `oninput` instead, that will call the function whenever the entered value changes. https://jsfiddle.net/82npv5bf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use `onkeyup` event in below code so that whenever user will type any name the function will get called to perform necessary operation.

**Demo Code** :

```js
function ViewType(val) {

  var op = document.getElementById("selectbtn").getElementsByTagName("option");
  for (var i = 0; i < op.length; i++) {
    if (val.toLowerCase() == "amit") {
      //checking if option value is not mceh 
      if (op[i].value != "MECH") {
        //disable other option
        op[i].disabled = true;
      }
    } else {
      //enable all options
      op[i].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Name of the candidate: </label><br>
<input type="text" name="e_name" onKeyup="ViewType(this.value);">
<br><br>
<label for="division">Choose Division</label><br>
<select name="e_division" id="selectbtn">
  <option>Select One</option>
  <option value="MECH">MECH</option>
  <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
  <option value="CE">CE</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<label for="name">Name of the candidate: </label><br>
<input id="candidate-name" type="text" name="e_name" value="" onfocus="ViewType(this.value);">
<br><br>
<label for="division">Choose Division</label><br>
<select name="e_division" id="selectbtn">
  <option>Select One</option>
  <option value="MECH">MECH</option>
  <option>CSE</option>
  <option>CE</option>
</select>
```

### JS

```
var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate-name");

candidate.addEventListener("change", viewType);

function viewType() {
  var select = document.getElementById("selectbtn");
  var op = select.getElementsByTagName("option");

  if(candidate.value == "Amit") {
    op[2].disabled = true;
    op[3].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am also stacked into the same problem asked above. I have tested this code by putting the value="Amit" into the first input tag. So that to run your solution. But it is not working.

Comment: The code is definitely working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/29up1ehm/2/